# How to pinpoint and resolve conflict caused by multiple external Javascript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While building a page, I have imported multiple (more than 10) external CSS and Javascript, including but not limited to timerangepicker, bootstrap and tabber.

The problem is, there seems to be some conflict when all of them load together, as they cause my UI to be totally messed up (some elements would show up in the wrong places, some features such as timerangepicker won't work).

I'm pretty sure the conflict is caused by all these files loading together, because some UI will become normal again when I disable some of the external files. These are the external files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/style.css">
    <link href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/tabber.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/styles-pop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEBSITE;?>/js/tabs_slides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEBSITE;?>/js/tabber.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo WEBSITE; ?>/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../templates/layout/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/browsebootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE; ?>/css/checkbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/ver02/search_payment.css">
    <script src="<?php echo WEBSITE; ?>/js/browse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scrollbar.css">
    <link href="css/topmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I know there are some redundancies,  but strangely, some of the features will only work if I put it this way.

My question is, how do I pinpoint exactly which files are in conflict with which files? There are just too many of them. And how can I avoid the conflict?

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: You can debug your site with https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0):

First move is to strip of the duplicate file references. For example you have 4 referenced jquery files of different vesions. Use  just one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/style.css">
<link href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/tabber.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/styles-pop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEBSITE;?>/js/tabs_slides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEBSITE;?>/js/tabber.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE; ?>/css/checkbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP_WEBSITE;?>/css/ver02/search_payment.css">
<script src="<?php echo WEBSITE; ?>/js/browse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scrollbar.css">
<link href="css/topmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/font-awesome-animation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a logical move. I have done exactly this, and some of the UI makes more sense now, but the problem is still not 100% solved. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll advise you remove all these files; include a line and test the interface, include another test until youve tested all files. This will guide you in detecting the problematic scripts. [The structure on your HTML also matters]

Comment: I guess that's the only way to do it. Thanks very much!